# How to run a command line script in Python

Tags: python-3.x

If I have a command line like this:

```
abc -c config.json| xyz -c test.json
```

How can I run it in Python file? I mean we will don't type "`abc -c config.json| xyz -c test.json`" in the terminal.
`xyz` and `abc` are applications that I have written.

So, May I have a help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im a little confused by your question.

If you want to make a system call from within python you would use the subprocess module

```
x = subprocess.Popen("ls /home", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()
```

If you want to run a python command from the command line you can either write it to a file and execute

```
python myFile.py
```

Or, run the commands directly to python

```
python -c "print("testing")"
```

Comment: Sorry, I just updated my question. Yes, I know subprocess, but how can I run the with the command line like this: abc -c config.json| xyz -c test.json.

Comment: I tried: 
subprocess.Popen(shlex.split("abc -c config.json| xyz -c test.json"), stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE) But It's not work for me.

Comment: what is "abc" and what is "xyz"? are these applications that you have written?

Comment: Yes, these are applications that I have written, @samson4649.

Comment: why are you using "shlex.split() ?                                                                                 you should be able to run -> subprocess.Popen( "abc -c config.json| xyz -c test.json", stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

Comment: if you need to split the output save the output of subprocess.Popen to a variable then split against it.

Comment: Hi, @samson4649! Thanks for your help. But I already found the solution. And it's here: subprocess.run("abc -c config.json| xyz -c test.json", shell=True, check=True)

Answer (score 3):

You can use this

`os.system("abc -c config.json| xyz -c test.json")`

This is like running `abc -c config.json| xyz -c test.json` in command prompt.